# ¿Que tan eficiente es pasar una llave como foránea a todas las tablas descendientes?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, datatable

tengo un proyecto viejo donde se me entrego una base de datos para rehacerla con mejoras, entre las cosas que vi estaba que la llave primaria de cada entidad estaba como llave foranea en todas las tablas que hijas y nietas, etc.
ej: imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿existe alguna razon para hacer esto?
¿tiene algo de bueno o alguna desventaja en cuanto a las consultas?
¿no seria redundante repetir las llaves?
en especial cuaando la relacion entre 2 tablas te puede igual llevar a la tabla que necesites haciendo join...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Esto es un datawarehouse seria correcto. Esta clase de preguntas no se puede contestar sin saber las reglas del negocio. Podria o no estar bien. No hay una regla clara escrita en base de datos, todo depende

Comment: en efecto como te comentan hay que entender primero cual es la regla del negocio con que fin se creo dichas tablas o que pretenden hacer las mismas

Comment: @gbianchi Parte de la pregunta sí tiene respuesta objetiva: *¿tiene algo de bueno o alguna desventaja en cuanto a las consultas?*. Si quieres listar todos los barrios de una provincia a menudo, en este caso no necesitarías joins. Simplificas las búsquedas, pero tiene un coste....

Comment: por eso @PabloLozano.. depende si es un datawarehouse u otra cosa ;)

Comment: Gracias, sus comentarios son precisamente lo que queria entender, osea que no es una mala praxis, sino que depende de como voy a estar buscando la data al utilizar la BD....? @PabloLozano